# Weird LocationListener through GPS provider behavior Android : "updateGps : GPS is on, but not receiving fixes"

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I'd a application that worked fine at getting users GPS location through LocationListener. I might have changed something but it's not working anymore.

The bug seems to be related to the provider LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, if I'm using LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER it works. So I think the problem is related to the GPS. I can see something weird in the log :

```
1-28 16:52:23.120: D/StatusBarPolicy(2815): [GPS ICON] updateGps : GPS is on, but not receiving fixes
```

Permissions in the manifest are ok :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And I can't find more relevant info.

I've already tried basic clean / restart on my Eclipse and device (I'm not testing on emulator). I'm about to get mad, does anyone as any idea about what to try before that ?

**EDIT :**

Here is some stupid simple code that doesn't work too. Am I missing something ?

```
package com.mytest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTestActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        Log.v("test", "launched");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("test", "location received ! "+location.getLatitude()+";"+location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("test", "location provider disabled");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("test", "location provider enabled");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.v("test", "location provider status changed");

    }
}
```

**EDIT** : see Daniele's answer comments

Comment: "What to try?" - Why not take the phone outside and see what happens?

Comment: Done, see in Daniele's answer comments... It changes nothing

Comment: I suggest you download the free app 'GPS Test' from the Android Market and install it on the device. It will show you how many satellites are visible and in use, plus SNR of signals.

Comment: I've more than one satellites in views most of the time, but none used.

Comment: @Aster, you need at least 4 satellites visible with a good SnR and you have to wait for 10 - 20 mintues. If the phone is connected to the internet you can get a fix in under 2 minutes.

Comment: By comparing with another device it occures that my GPS was not working correctly, a factory reset fixed that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you inside a building? Could it be that the GPS is simply unable to get a fix? If it worked previously it was (probably) because you was reading the last known location from the GPS. The description of your issue makes me think that there is no issue...

Daniele

Comment: I'm inside a building yes, but Google Maps have access to the GPS location.

Comment: Google Maps may be using a cached GPS location. It really sounds like your GPS radio can't get fixes.

Comment: I strongly think it's not the case. I'm in the same position, in the same office, at less one meter of a 2 cm glass window...

Comment: I've took a walk, 100 % sure that it's not linked with a GPS block in the building.

Comment: The issue was that my device wasn't working correctly, the GPS didn't send any values. A factory reset fixed that problem.